# Change background for everything in mail without one div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have to change contrast in my whole site, but in one div I have things that needs to remain unchanged

```js
var color_text = ["initial", "#00FF21", "#fff"];
var color_background = ["initial", "#f00", "#000"];
var ile = 1;

$('.kontrast').click(function() {

  $('#main *').css("color", color_text[ile]);
  $('#main *').css("background", color_background[ile]);
  ile = (ile + 1) % 3;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="kontrast" href="#">Contrast</a>


<div id="main">
  <h3>A little bit of text </h3>
  <p>z A little bit of text .</p>
  <p><strong>A little bit of text</strong>
  </p>
  <p>A little bit of text</p>
  <p><a href="#">Download .pdf</a>
  </p>

  <div class="not_this">
    <p><a href="#">I don't want to change this</a></p>

  </div>

</div>
```

How can I change everything except `<div class="not_this">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `:not(".not_this")` and can be **shortened** to:

```
$('.kontrast').click(function() {

  $('#main *:not(.not_this)').css({
    "color": color_text[ile],
    "background": color_background[ile]
  });
  ile = (ile + 1) % 3;
});
```

Comment: Good! And if I have to excluded more than one specific classes in #main ? I do not know what syntax is correct

Comment: Yeah, no problem, you can use `*:not(.not_1,.not_2)`. All selectors are accepted inside `:not()`, for example: `:not(div a)` and `:not(div,a)`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!